# Configure Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, webapi

I have a web api in net core 3.1 and I am trying to configure swagger but I get this error:
[image]

I currently have the startup.cs configured as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            AddSwagger(services);

        }

private void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                var groupName = "v1";

                options.SwaggerDoc(groupName, new OpenApiInfo
                { Title = "Core Library", Version = "v1", });
            });
        }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Core Library");
                c.RoutePrefix = String.Empty;
                c.DocumentTitle = "";
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                endpoints.MapControllers());
        }
```

What else will I be missing? Can you help me?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use inspect on the browser and open the `Console` tab, click on `v1/swagger/json:1` file to get details about the error message

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Merna Mustafa! I could see that the error was in a method that did not have the prefix (httppost). Again thank you very much!!